# C++0x: uniform_real_distribution is not a member of std

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I am trying to compile my first piece of code using c++0x. I am pretty good with C++, but this one has me stumped. The following will not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
   unsigned     seed = 12345;
   std::mt19937 generator(seed);

   std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distro1(0.0, 1.0);
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
   {
      std::cout << "Help" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Value  ==  " << distro1(generator) << std::endl;
   }
}
```

I compile with the following:

```
g++ -std=c++0x myFile.cpp or with g++ -std=gnu++0x myFile.cpp
```

The errors I am getting are:

```
myFile.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
myFile.cpp:11: error: ‘uniform_real_distribution’ is not a member of ‘std’
myFile.cpp:11: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
myFile.cpp:11: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘double’
myFile.cpp:15: error: ‘distro1’ was not declared in this scope
```

G++ is:
   `g++ --version`
   `g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5`

Oddly enough it compiles past the mt19937 instantiation and if I just call `mt19937::operator()` I get output as expected. Also if I switch distributions to normal_distribution it compiles and outputs the "Help " line, but does nothing else. The process can be seen running via `ps aux`, but no output.

Am I missing something stupid? I essentially copied the code from cplusplus.com to show a mwe. Thanks for you help

Comment: Perhaps it's just not implemented?

Comment: What version is your STL?

Comment: Probably your compiler is just too old. Compiles with 4.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

You have to upgrade to a later version of your compiler (your program compiles fine on GCC 4.7.2). The implementation of the standard library that ships with GCC 4.4.5 is clearly not (fully) C++11 compliant.

Comment: @ultima_rat0: That's the core language support though. I could not find a similar page for standard library coverage

Comment: I had assumed it was something stupid, but didn't think g++ would release with only part of the standard implemented. Will have to look into a compiler upgrade

Comment: @Andy: you're right - that was just to show the missing implementations.

Comment: @jml2307, To this day, no compiler has all of C++11. They're doing pretty well, though. For example, GCC 4.8.1 has the compiler side pretty good. The library is being finished.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Here http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x  Note however that unlike core language features, the stdlib status is not broken down per compiler version, it just reflects the current status ("latest and greatest").

Comment: @syam: Indeed, I found that as well, but that's not useful to answer the OP's question since - as you correctly noticed - it just reports the current status

Comment: @AndyProwl: yeah unfortunately. But since it can still be useful sometimes and you said you didn't find "a similar page" I figured I'd mention it anyway. And it was a good thing too, apparently it's useful at least to chris. :)

Comment: I am actually surprised about the lack of historical records about the content of `libstdc++` versions. Will spend some time looking for this soon and report my findings here.

Comment: @jml2307 - gcc **used** to be pretty good about not releasing junky libraries. The current implementation of `<regex>` shows that they're now going down a different path.